# A mathematical statement about Laplace's equation from famous physicist Landau's book

Tags: mathematical-physics, harmonic-functions

In the book titled *Classical Theory of Fields*, by famous Physicist Landau, writes,

From $\nabla^2\phi(x,y,z)=0$,

> ...it follows, in particular, that the potential $\phi$ of the electric field can nowhere have a maximum or a minimum. For in order that $\phi$ have an extreme value, it would be necessary that the first derivatives of $\phi$ w.r.t the coordinates be zero, and that the second derivatives, $\partial^2\phi/\partial x^2,\partial^2\phi/\partial y^2,\partial^2\phi/\partial z^2$ all have the same sign. The last is impossible since the Laplace's equation cannot be satisfied.

Is it true that the second derivatives $\partial^2\phi/\partial x^2,\partial^2\phi/\partial y^2,\partial^2\phi/\partial z^2$ must necessarily have the same sign at a local extremum i.e., all negative for local maximum and all positive for a local minimum? Thinking geometrically, probably the answer is yes. But I am not sure.

Comment: I think that the *necessary* condition for extrema is only $\nabla \phi=0$. Hessian condition is the sufficient condition, right?

Comment: I am asking how rigorous is this statement mathematically and hence, in this site. Is it true that the second derivatives $\partial^2\phi/\partial x^2,\partial^2\phi/\partial y^2,\partial^2\phi/\partial z^2$ must necessarily have the same sign at a local extremum i.e., all negative for local maximum and all positive for a local minimum? Thinking geometrically, probably the answer is yes. But I am not sure.

Comment: @KurtG.: The condition of the Hessian being positive definite is certainly *not* necessary; see my answer below.

Comment: @KurtG. for a twice-differentiable function, at a local minimum point, the second derivative is only guaranteed to be positive semidefinite, so the trace (which is the Laplacian) is merely guaranteed to be non-negative. This does not contradict having trace $0$ (i.e being harmonic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument is not correct. Even at a *strict* local extremum, all second partial derivatives can be zero; consider for example $\phi(x,y,z) = x^4+y^4+z^4$ at the point $(0,0,0)$.

(Correct statements and proofs of the weak/strong maximum principles can be found in many PDE textbooks.)